# How to solve > Additional information: HRESULT: 0x8007000B

Tags: f#

An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in ConsoleApplication32.exe

Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

I changed the platform from x64 to x86 from the configuration settings......the compiler still keeps on giving the errors.......Also I am administrator in Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: what is the bitness of the add.dll file?

Comment: BadImageFormatException definitely implies that your application is using a platform target that doesn't match that of the dll you are trying to call.  I see in your screenshot you are in fact using Any CPU, have you toggled on/off prefer 32 bit in the project settings?

Comment: @TheInnerLight : I changed the AnyCPU to x86, but still got the same resul.  Project-->Console Application Properties---> Platform Active x86-->Platform target x86

Comment: @Yacoub Massad: Add.dll is made in the VB6 by converting the script to a dll file    Public Function AddTwoNumbers(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long) As Long
  AddTwoNumbers = a + b
End Function